# Bash: How to determine if a variable was set within the command or exported in the parent?

Tags: bash

Is there a bash-centric way to tell whether an environment variable was set on the command line in the parent shell, or exported beforehand?

e.g. from `my_script.sh` can we distinguish whether variable `A` was set via method 1 or 2:

1. `A=1 ./my_script.sh`
2. `export A=1; ./my_script.sh`

*Note: For simplicity let's assume the parent shell is bash, and the interpreter for my_script.sh is also bash.*

Comment: What's the use case?

Answer (score 1):

It's bound to be a bit iffy to do that, since from the viewpoint of `./my_script.sh`, the envvar is exactly the same. But you can use `extdebug`, a `DEBUG` trap and `$BASH_COMMAND` to look at the command that was run, and it appears to include variable assignments, too...

```
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ trap 'export CMDLINE=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
$ env |grep CMDLINE
CMDLINE=env
$ foo=bar env |grep CMDLINE
CMDLINE=foo=bar env
```

You'll still have to parse the string to pick up the assignments, which may be hairy to get right if there can be multiple of them (e.g. `foo='some strings'"$(comm subst)"\ this\ too A=1 ./myscript.sh`)

But for the simple case, just looking for a leading `A=` probably works.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

- NO

Now you can verify that there is no semantic difference between variable exported inline with the command or exported by the export command:

- Testing inline:

```sh
$ unset A
$ A='hello inline export' bash -c 'declare -p A'
declare -x A="hello inline export"
```

- Testing export command:

```sh
$ unset A
$ A='hello export'
$ export A
$ bash -c 'declare -p A'
declare -x A="hello export"
```

In both cases, bash sees variables as `declare -x A=...` which is the normal declaration for an exported variable.

Comment: thank you. the fact that flags are the same led me to ask this question. I am hoping there is another way to tell, which may not involve the set of declare flags on the variable. e.g. by reading the command (verbatim) invoked by the parent, or a way to diff the child and the parent's environment.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, you can know the difference with this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
echo "in test.sh's environment, A=$A"
mapfile -d "" environ < /proc/$PPID/environ
for item in "${environ[@]}"; do
    test "${item#A=}" = "$item" || { echo "[$item] is in parent's initial environment."; exit; }
done
echo "A is not in parent's initial environment."
```

```
~/tmp$ unset A; bash
~/tmp$ A=1 ./test.sh
in test.sh's environment, A=1
A is not in parent's initial environment.
~/tmp$ 
~/tmp$ A=1 bash
~/tmp$ ./test.sh
in test.sh's environment, A=1
[A=1] is in parent's initial environment.
```

The problem is that /proc/pid/environ is not dynamic. So the script cannot catch the case of `export A=1`

Comment: Very interesting, even though it doesn't really answer the question. This answer is more about whether the parent or some grand-grand-parent exported the variable, not about the difference between `export A=1; cmd` and `A=1 cmd`. Anyways, with GNU grep you might also use `[ "$(grep -z '^A=' /proc/$PPID/environ = "A=$A" ] && echo 'A was already exported before parent ran' || echo 'parent changed A' `.

Comment: `This answer is more about whether the parent or some
grand-grand-parent exported the variable` - well, as OP said
themselves, not exactly.